# Bootstrap CSS radio button broken in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I'm using bootstrap CSS and i have a form that use radio button , it works in Chrome 
and when i use Firefox the labels and the button collapses.

Here is the code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="registerResult.php">

            <fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
                    <label  class="control-label">Gender :</label>
                        <label class="radio">
                           <div class="controls"><input type="radio" name="sexe" id="optionsRadios1" value="male" checked></div>
                         Male
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio">
                            <div class="controls"><input type="radio" name="sexe" id="optionsRadios1" value="female" checked></div>
                          Female
                        </label>
                </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is the screenshot :
[image: Bootstrap CSS radio button broken in Firefox screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label">Gender:</label>
   <div class="controls">
      <label class="radio">
         <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male"> Male
      </label>
      <label class="radio">
         <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female"> Female
      </label>
      <label class="radio">
         <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Other"> Other
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```